# MySQL stored procedure, order by DESC / ASC with condition

Tags: sql-order-by

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM Tbl
ORDER BY
IF (VariableA > VariableB , C1 DESC , C1 ASC);
```

- Here VariableA and VariableB are the variables declared in
- Stored procedure

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This might help -

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM Tbl
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN VariableA > VariableB THEN C1 END DESC ,
CASE WHEN VariableA <= VariableB THEN C1 END ASC;
```

It should be noted that we don't include an ELSE for each CASE, which means any other value will return NULL and be discarded from the ORDER BY.

Comment: You missed a `THEN` in your second case statement.